# Angular Chosen not Updating from API Call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-chosen

I am populating a select box with angular [chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen/releases):

```
<select ng-change="checkSelection()" 
        chosen="" 
        class="form-control chosen-select input-md" 
        data-placeholder="Select a Thing" 
        ng-model="theThing" 
        ng-options="thing.name for thing in things"></select>
```

When I hardcode the list of things in the Controller, this does works, but when I set the `things` in a success function of an http call (which succeeds) the box is not populated:

```
     $scope.getThings = function() {
        $http.get('/rest/Things', {}).
            success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
               $scope.things = data;
            }).
            error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("Could not get list of things " + data);
            });
    }
```

Does not work.  How can I get the select to update?

Comment: What is the exact 'angular chosen' module you are using? There are a few out there, some better than others.

Comment: what version of angular are you using ? `.success()` and `.error()` callbacks are now deprecated. Have you tried to `console.log()` the API response to see if it is empty or if this is just a matter of outdated $scope?